# How to find friend_id list of facebook?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api, ios5

How to friend Friend id list on Facebook for iPhone sdk?

https://graph.facebook.com/me/friend?access_token=your access token.

Answer (score 4):

//Friends: https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?access_token=your access token

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];


[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?access_token=%@", token]]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];

NSError *error;
NSURLResponse *response;
NSData *returnData=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];

NSString *returnString=[[NSString alloc]initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"%@",returnString);  
SBJSON *json = [[SBJSON new] autorelease];

dic = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:[json objectWithString:returnString error:nil]];

FriendIdArr=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:[dic valueForKey:@"data"]];
```

// FriendIdArr is final friend id list array